# JSON parsing error: org.json.JSONException: Index 6 out of range

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I started a thread here about parsing a nested array:
[How do you return the contents of the following nested JSON Array in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090436/how-do-you-return-the-contents-of-the-following-nested-json-array-in-android)

I'm downloading a list of subway stations in a line from the following url:
https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/victoria/Route/Sequence/inbound?serviceTypes=Regular,Night

The stations are enclosed in a nested array. I need to extract "id" and "name" from the "stopPoint" array nested in the"stopPointSequences" array. I'm using AsyncTask and storing the list in a RecyclerView Adapter. I'm not using HashMap or GSON. Only one to four items are being displayed.

The app isn't crashing but the above index error is on this line(code below):
 JSONObject innerElem = stopPointArrayList.getJSONObject(i);

Also, the warning for the "for"statement above it is that it "statement has empty body". I came across this thread:

[Error org.json.JSONException: Index 2 out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523917/error-org-json-jsonexception-index-2-out-of-range)

I changed "i" to "j" in the nested "for" statement, but "j" isn't recognized.

Thank you in advance.

To moderator. Is it alright if I post a link to my other thread and not copy and paste all of the code here?

JSONUtils class:

```
      public static ArrayList<Stations> extractFeatureFromStationJson(String stationJSON)
    {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stationJSON))
        {
            return null;
        }
       ArrayList<Stations> stations = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(stationJSON);
            JSONArray stopPointSequenceArrayList = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("stopPointSequences");
            if (stopPointSequenceArrayList != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < stopPointSequenceArrayList.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject elem = stopPointSequenceArrayList.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (elem != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray stopPointArrayList = elem.getJSONArray("stopPoint");
                        if (stopPointArrayList != null) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < stopPointArrayList.length(); j++) ;
                            {
                                JSONObject innerElem = stopPointArrayList.getJSONObject(j);
                                if (innerElem != null) {
                                    String idStation = "";
                                    if (innerElem.has("id")) {
                                        idStation = innerElem.optString(KEY_STATION_ID);
                                    }
                                    String nameStation = "";
                                    if (innerElem.has("name")) {
                                        nameStation = innerElem.optString(KEY_STATION_NAME);
                                    }
                                    Stations station = new Stations(idStation, nameStation);
                                    stations.add(station);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing stations JSON results", e);
        }
        // Return the list of stations
        return stations;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of the clients like Volley or Retrofit2 for getting data from the apis

once you get the data , map the data using Gson library and then u can use the data as per your requirement

you will have response listeners onsuccess and onfailure listeners

Comment: I'm using AsyncTask to download the data: not just for this activity but the entire app. It works. Here, only 2 out 25 items are being downloaded. How can I check what's causing it?

Comment: is ur api response has 25 items

Comment: I checked several times and the url has all the data I need. Link above. Parse data available. Thank you.

Comment: Question updated along with the error message. Thank you.

Comment: Solved! The code is correct. There was an inexplicable error in Android Studio. Thank you again for answering. To moderator: is it possible to delete this thread?